# Differences between mousemove and touchnove

Tags: javascript, android, mousemove, touchmove

Mousemove event in javascript is triggered once every tot ms.IsToucmove event the same?I am asking this because I see that in Android moving your finger very fast the movements are fluid instead with mousemove are less fluid

Answer (score 0):

Touch events have a **300ms** delay in order for the browser to determine if the user is performing multi-touch or any kind of gestures .

Also touch event fire `touch` and `click` handlers at the same time ..

Mouse events alone have no delay because no touch gestures are expected on desktop ..

This link may help also :

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/touchandmouse/

Comment: Of you move your mouse fast,onmousemove isn't triggered every pixel you move it.So I think this event has a delay.On a touch screen for example is touchmove event  triggered every pixel the user move his finger?